# Change class value using CSS

Tags: css

I would like to change "Email adress / Email" to other value. Is it possible by using CSS?
Could you help me with this please?

````
<label class="edd-label" for="edd-email">
                Email adress / Email                                    
<span class="edd-required-indicator">*</span>
                            </label>```

I was trying to change it like this:

```label.edd-label.edd-email {
visibility: hidden;
}```
It does not work
````

Comment: You'd have to hide the label and then add an :after, which wouldn't be accessible to assistive technology like screen readers. So it would be much better to filter or translate the text instead.

Comment: how can I hide label? On the other hand, I need to hide some of these classes but I don't have any ideas where I have to start.
Thank you for response @WebElaine

Comment: From the markup you've provided it looks like you should be targeting `label.edd-label`. You have it as `label.edd-label.edd-email` but there is no `"edd-email"` class on the label, which is why that's not working.

Comment: Ok, I can try, but if I have a 4 '''label.edd-label''' and each of them has the '''label.edd-label''' a cant change all of them independently. If you know what I mean.

Comment: You may also have to use `:nth-child` etc. to target the right one. Play around with developer tools to see what does and doesn't work.